# Get terms of the posts with one query

Tags: php, filters

I need to get the terms for 2.000 posts. 
How can I do this without making 2000 queries?
Is it possible to get terms of the post in the post_object with a filter or something similar?

```
wp_get_post_terms($mobile_id->ID , 'brand',$args )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts a, wp_term_relationships b, wp_terms c WHERE a.post_status = 'published' AND a.ID = b.object_id AND b.term_id = c.term_id;
```

This will list all the post that is in the published state and then its terms.

You can add limits and offsets to limit the number of records.

Comment: I change my system to avoid the problem but I like your answer.

Comment: what did u change

Comment: I saved the data in php cache so I dont ask the db.